# Probability question math please?

Tags: probability

> a) We have $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ which are three events. Write the event: at most one event happens.

Solution: I dont know :S

> b) We have $A$, $B$ and $C$, three independent events with $P(A)=\frac{1}{4}$, $P(B)=\frac{1}{3}$, and $P(C)=\frac{1}{2}$.
>   Find the probability that none of them happens.
>   Find the probability that a certain event happens.

Solution : Probability=0
Solution : 1/4+1/3+1/2

Are these right, and please, can you help me with the first one?

Comment: For the second one, should be clear that the probability cannot be zero... The second solution has a probability greater than 1, can this be right?

Comment: What do you mean by "the probability that a certain event happens"? If an event is "certain", then the probability of it happening is 1. That's the definition of the word "certain".

Comment: continued ... maybe you mean "the probability that at least one event happens". If that's what you mean, then Emanuele's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

a) 
$$
 (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) \setminus ((A_1 \cap A_2) \cup (A_1 \cap A_3) \cup (A_2 \cap A_3))
$$

b1) the complementary of each event happens:
$$
  x=(1-1/4) (1-1/3) (1-1/2)
$$

b2) the complementary of b1
$$
1-x
$$